# Adding an item to an already populated combobox

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I have populated a combobox with an **QSqlQueryModel**. It's all working fine as it is, but I would like to add an extra item to the combobox that could say **"ALL_RECORDS"**. This way I could use the combobox as a filtering device.

I obviously don't want to add this extra item in the database, how can I add it to the combobox after it's been populated by a model?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a proxy model that takes gets it's data from two models, one for your default values, the other for your database, and use it to populate your `QComboBox`.

Comment: I had a very similar problem, wanting to add a 'None' option to a QComboBox, and did it this way. I'd recommend using a QAbstractListModel subclass, instantiated with a reference to the QSqlQueryModel so it can populate itself from the database and manage the 'special' entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
select "ALL RECORDS" union (select 'field' from table)
```

as query for the model.

This way you get the "ALL RECORDS" as first item and then all the others values, but not in order (this is a mysql issue anyway)

If you want also the values in the table to be ordered, you should look at this message

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?97,144205,241169#msg-241169

which explain a possible solution, given that you use MySql

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I thought I could solve it on the MySql query, was just trying to avoid it since I am using the model in several widgets. I guess I will have to make a model specially for this combobox. Thanks again!